# Activity calling itself -: Shared Preferences being cleared on pressing back button

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am using the following activity that keeps on calling itself. Things are working fine when I go in the forward direction but as soon as I click the back button, the shared preferrences is cleared.

```
   SharedPreferences userLocalDatabase;
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_paper_dashboard);

            userLocalDatabase = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
            name = userLocalDatabase.getString("name", "");
            subject = userLocalDatabase.getString("subject", "");
            timeLeft = userLocalDatabase.getInt("timeLeft", -1);
            quesNo = userLocalDatabase.getInt("quesNo", -1);
            no_of_ques = userLocalDatabase.getInt("no_of_ques", -1);
            score = userLocalDatabase.getInt("score", -1);
            currentLine = quesNo+1;

            Log.i("TAG2", "Krishna the score returned from Shared Preferences is -: " +score);

            myQuesTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myQuesTitle);
            myTimer = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myTimer);
            myQuestion = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.myQuestion);

            myFinish = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myFinish);
            myPrevious = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myPrevious);
            myAnswer = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myAnswer);
            myHint = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myHint);
            myNext = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.myNext);

            myAnswer1 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.myAnswer1);
            myAnswer2 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.myAnswer2);
            myAnswer3 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.myAnswer3);
            myAnswer4 = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.myAnswer4);

            String line = setLayout(name, timeLeft, quesNo, no_of_ques);
            Log.i("TAG2", "Krishna the line returned is -: " + line);
        }
```

this is the method for calling -:

```
   public void clickPrevious(View v){

   calculateScore();
    SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
    spEditor.putString("name", name);
    spEditor.putString("subject", subject);
    spEditor.putInt("timeLeft", timeLeft);
    spEditor.putInt("no_of_ques", no_of_ques);
    spEditor.putInt("quesNo", 0);
    spEditor.putInt("score", 0 );
    spEditor.commit();
    Log.i("TAG2", "Baladeva score is -: " + score);
    finish();
    startActivity(new Intent(paper_dashboard.this, paper_dashboard.class));
}
```

posting the Next method-:

```
    public void clickNext(View v){

            calculateScore();
            SharedPreferences.Editor spEditor = userLocalDatabase.edit();
            spEditor.putString("name", name);
            spEditor.putString("subject", subject);
            spEditor.putInt("timeLeft", timeLeft);
            spEditor.putInt("no_of_ques", no_of_ques);
            spEditor.putInt("quesNo", quesNo+1);
            spEditor.putInt("score", score);
            spEditor.commit();
            Log.i("TAG2", "Baladeva score is -: " + score);
            Intent intent = new Intent(new Intent(this, paper_dashboard.class));
            //intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by forward direction

Comment: Actually I am making an exam app that uses the same activity for displaying different questions. So I am using 2 buttons, forward and backword

Comment: also post your forward() function and how do you know your shared preferences are getting cleared ? where are you assigning value to all the variables which you are storing in shared Preferences ? viz. name , subject etc ?

Comment: Surely there's a better navigation pattern for this. E.g., Fragments, a ViewPager, a combination of the two, etc.

Comment: This is in one activity -: 12-12 18:09:34.427  10191-10191/? I/TAG2﹕ Baladeva score is -: 3
On going to new activity we see that score =0
12-12 18:09:34.535  10191-10191/? I/TAG2﹕ Krishna the score returned from Shared Preferences is -: 0

Comment: You are writing 0 to your score shared preference in `clickPrevious`. Here's your code: `spEditor.putInt("score", 0 );`